# Passing service url as environment to another service in docker-compose using traefik

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

can you please help me understand and fix the following issue?
I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy for my backend using traefik.

My goal is to to pass the the database url as environment variable to the backend service.
Currently I'm passing the server's public ip address which I'd like to avoid.

Thank you for your help.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.caserver=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=my-email"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt

  landing:
    image: rg.fr-par.scw.cloud/project1/project1-new-front:0.11
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.landing.rule=Host(`www.project1.app`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.landing.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.landing.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.landing.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
  
  backend:
    platform: linux/arm64
    image: myregistery/project1/project1-backend:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`api.project1.app`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
    environment:
      - USER=prod
      - DB_URL=??
      - DB_PORT=4400
    depends_on:
      - surreal-db
  
  surreal-db:
    image: surrealdb/surrealdb:latest
    user: root    
    command: start --user root --pass root file:/project1-data/data
    ports:
      - "4400:8000"
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.surrealdb.rule=Host(`surrealdb.docker.localhost`)"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; the hostname component of database url is always going to be `surreal-db`. What other information do you need?

Comment: I tried to pass surreal-db as value for the environment variable DB_URL but I get connexion refused.

Comment: You probably have a race condition (your application is trying to connect to the database before the database is ready to handle connections).